# Как отключить boostrap для определенного блока

Tags: bootstrap

Нужно использовать плагин http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ , в частности режим вывода всех дней года. Как сделать так, чтобы Bootstrap не переопределял стили для определенного блока?

Comment: Не задавать классы бутстрапа определенному блоку.

Comment: Какие стили в каком блоке надо уберечь от бутстрапа? Добавьте в вопрос фрагменты HTML и CSS, чтобы получить более конкретный ответ на свой вопрос.